# In a UML state machine, can an initial pseudostate have incoming transitions?

Tags: uml

In UML 2.5.1, the *initial* pseudostate of a state machine is defined as follows:

> An initial Pseudostate represents a starting point for a Region; that
>   is, it is the point from which execution of its contained behavior
>   commences when the Region is entered via default activation. It is the
>   source for at most one Transition, which may have an associated effect
>   Behavior, but not an associated trigger or guard. There can be at
>   most one initial Vertex in a Region.

In other words, a UML state machine should almost always contain exactly one initial pseudostate, which should have exactly one *outgoing* transition.

**However, can an initial pseudostate have *incoming* transitions as well? For example:**

[image]

I cannot find anything forbidding it in the UML specification, yet I cannot find any example online where this case happen, therefore I was wondering whether or not I overlooked anything.

---

*EDIT:* To go into more detail, if we look into the OCL constraints stated in the specification, we can only find the following one that affects outgoing transitions (section 14.5.6.7):

`inv: (kind = PseudostateKind::initial) implies (outgoing->size() <= 1)`

but I cannot find any constraint regarding incoming transitions

---

*EDIT2:* I have just realized that my model is wrong! Considering this sentence of the specification (cited above): "It is the source for at most one Transition, which may have an associated effect Behavior, **but not an associated trigger** or guard."

Therefore the transition between *init* and *s1* should actually have zero triggers, instead of having *e1* as a trigger.

Note that while this does not invalidate the initial question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see nothing in the [UML 2.5.1 Specification](https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5.1/PDF) that prohibits a transition whose target is the initial pseudostate.

Such a transition would be meaningless at best and confusing at worst, which is likely why no examples are found.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: see the comments!

On p. 423 UML 2.5:

> **15.7.18 InitialNode [Class]**
>
> **15.7.18.4 Constraints**
>
> • no_incoming_edges
>
> An InitialNode has no incoming ActivityEdges.
>
> ```
>   inv: incoming->isEmpty()
> ```

N.B. If you intend to have a self-transition for `e1` then why not just using that? The `Initial` can anyway have only on singular outgoing edge, namely to the first state (here `s1`).

Comment: Chapter 15 of the spec concerns Activities, whereas the question is about State Machines (chapter 14).

Comment: @jaco0646 you have a point there. They are both derived from Petri nets and if it's missing for SM then this is likely a bug in the specs.

Answer (score 0):

No this is not allowed. And why would one Do that? As you already stated in the cited text,it can only have one outgoing  edge without any guard. So what is the added value, as you cannot reuse anything.

Comment: To clarify, I am not asking whether this would be a good idea or practice, I am just wondering whether it is valid UML. And regarding the cited text, it only states a constraint regarding outgoing transitions, not regarding incoming transitions, hence my question. In fact, only the amount of outgoing transitions of initial states is constrained using OCL (section 14.5.6.7 of the spec), and surprisingly there is no OCL constraint regarding the amount of incoming transitions.

Comment: Where does the UML spec say that it's not allowed?

Answer (score 0):

I think the text is pretty clear as-is: "[An initial Pseudostate] is the point from which execution of its contained behavior commences **when the Region is entered via default activation**." If you connect a transition back around to the initial psuedostate, the initial psuedostate is no longer "the point from which execution of its contained behavior commences," it is something else, and is therefore undefined.

Comment: The statement above does not exclude anything. If I say "a car can transport persons" then it does not mean it can't transport anything else.